# SQL update function doesn't throw any error message but it returns no rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a table value from another table. I want to update `pstatus` from `productcode`.

Here is my code (which gives no error and results 0 rows):

```
UPDATE pstatus
SET code=(select code FROM productcode)
```

besides this, I can't re-run any update in sql - it gives no error, but returns 0 rows (I have more than 5 rows in `productcode` table).

Comment: This _should_ give you an error of `productcode` has more than 1 row. What database are you using?

Comment: Do you have any records in the `pstatus` table?

Comment: i am using sql. no don't have any record on pstatus.

Comment: that statement, if your subquery returns only one value, will update field code in every row in pstatus field, with the same value

Comment: SQL is a query language, used by many different databases. What is the brand of the database that you are using? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Microsoft Access? Oracle? Any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have a two problem

1. you say you dont have any rows in pstatus if no record in table how can table row update ?
2. your inner query `select code FROM productcode` return more then one row then how sql decide to set with value in wich field?

Comment: your ans helps me. but when i insert data in productcode the pstatus table is not updating can you fix that?

Comment: if you want to make automatic update use trigger or you give a foreign key to another table

Answer (score 0):

An update statement doesn't return rows. You should have used something more like

```
Update pstatus
   Set code=a.code
  from productcode a
 where a.*somekeyfield* = *value*
```

You have to determine which single record from productcode you wish to use as the basis for the update. What *somekeyfield* should be is something you need to determine.

Comment: If you have no records in pstatus, then there is nothing to update. You must first insert records into pstatus, and *then* you can update them as needed.

Comment: Actually some DBMS *can* return rows from an UPDATE statement (by using a `RETURNING` clause)

Answer (score 0):

An update statemend doesn't add records, it only updates records that already exist in the table.

The `update` query does actually udpate all the records in the table, but as there are no records, the number of updated records is zero.

If you want to add records, you should use an `insert` query instead:

```
insert into pstatus (code)
select code from productcode
```

Comment: ya i tried this and it works but my productcode will be continue and also other tables from where i will insert the data to pstatus.in the insert into case data will be duplicate

Comment: @RahatIslamKhan: What do you mean by "will be continue"? If you want data from other tables you can just add them to the `select` using `join` or `union`.